# Merging different dictionary in python without updating the value stored

Tags: python, pandas, function, binary-search-tree, tf-idf

I have a tree structure where at every node idf values are stored for a large number of words. Dictionary has two fields i.e. word and idf.

I want to store all the idf values in a dictionary. I want all the value of idf which are stored in the tree to get stored in the dictionary, but when I am doing so it is storing only one value of each word.

For example: A has two childs B and C. A,B,C all has idf values stored at them. I want to make a dictionary which will combine all the idf values and store it together.

`A = {'a':10, 'b': 11} B = {'a':5, 'c': 8} C = {'b':21, 'd': 20}`, I want to store it as `dic = {'a':10,'a':5,'b':11,'b':21,'c':8,'d':20}`

Below is the code that I am using:

```
def idf_total(node):
    dic={}
    next_node=[]
    for child in node.children:
        next_node.append(child)
        idf = child.idf
        dic.update(idf)
    if next_node:
        for i in next_node:
            idf_total(i)
    return dic
```

Kindly help how this can be done.

Latest code:

```
def idf_total_updated(node):
    dic=defaultdict(list)
    next_node=[]
    for child in node.children:
        next_node.append(child)
        for k,v in child.idf.items():
            dic[k].append(v)
     if next_node:
        for i in next_node:
            idf_total_updated(i)
    return dic
```

The above latest code is storing multiple values for a key but it is repeating the same value again and again. Where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: can u post sample dictionary as well.

Comment: x = {'a':10, 'b': 11} y = {'a':5, 'c': 8} y = {'b':21, 'd': 20}, I want to store it as dic = {'a':10,'a':5,'b':11,'b':21,'c':8,'d':20

Comment: I dont see any child here

Comment: Please post a MCVE, test data and expected results for the test data.

Comment: A dictionary can not have duplicate keys

Comment: I have updated the question. Is there any other way in which I can do this. By creating a list or storing these values as a dataframe. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries **cannot** have duplicate keys.

This means you cannot have (for example):

```
C = {'a': 5, 'a': 10}  # key 'a' is duplicate here.
```

One way to solve this issue is to have a list of values for a key.

For example:

```
A = {'a': 5}
B = {'a': 10}
```

This can be combined into

```
C = {'a': [5, 10]}
```

`defaultdict` from `collections` module is appropriate here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = {'a': 10, 'b': 11} 
B = {'a': 5, 'c': 8}
C = {'b': 21, 'd': 20}

dic = defaultdict(list)

for d in A, B, C:
    for k, v in d.items():  # d.iteritems() in Python 2
        dic[k].append(v)
print(dic)

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [10, 5], 
#                              'b': [11, 21],
#                              'c': [8],
#                              'd': [20]})
```

Comment: I am using the following code but it is storing same values multiple times in the list for example, it is storing 'a':[10:10] for me. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong. Below is my code: def idf_total_updated(node):
    dic=defaultdict(list)
    next_node=[]
    for child in node.children:
        next_node.append(child)
        for k,v in child.idf.items():
            dic[k].append(v)
    if next_node:
        for i in next_node:
            idf_total_updated(i)
    return dic

Comment: Could you add code to question with proper formatting? It's hard to judge where indentation starts and ends.

Comment: I assume you don't need to store `10` again if you already have `10` in list. Is that right?

Comment: I want to store all the values even if they are repeated.

Comment: So, what's the issue with `'a': [10, 10]` ? It should be like that if you have `10` as value for key `a` in two dicts.

Comment: The issue with me is that I am not able to store all the values as a list together. If a should store 10,15,20...i am capturing only one value multiple times using the latest code which i shared. Can you please tell where i am going wrong with that code.

Comment: What do you pass to this function?

Comment: I am passing the parent node which contains multiple childs. All the nodes have idf values stored as dictionary to it. For e.g. A is the parent and has B and C as childs, so I am passing A to the function.

Comment: I don't know if this solves because I couldn't recreate your issue. Try placing `dic=defaultdict(list)` outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `update`:

```
A = {'a':10, 'b': 11} 
B = {'a':5, 'c': 8}
B.update(A)
>> B
>> {'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 8}
```

As you can not have a duplicate key with different value in a dict, it overrides the same keys with the key in `A` dictionary.
read the documentation here [Update](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm)

or if you have to keep both values you have to create a list of dictionaries like this:

```
l = [A, B, C]
```

Comment: I don't want to update the values. I just want to store all the possible values for a key together. Is there any other way around in which this can be done.

Comment: if `A={'a':1}` and `B={'a':5}`, what are you expect the final dict to be?
tell me i will figure it out for you. @adi5257

Comment: You may have the list of dict like this too `[A,B,C]` if desired.@adi5257

Comment: I want dic={'a':1,'a':5}...I know that a dictionary can't hold multiple values for same key but is there any other way in which this can be done. By creating a list or a dataframe.

Comment: yes i updated my answer, this is the only way left to do it. make them as a list o dicts.